# "The Resource Type could not be found." while using template composition

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

I'm trying to use [template composition](https://docs.openstack.org/heat/pike/template_guide/composition.html) with OpenStack Heat.

I've created a minimalist template `my-custom-resource.yml`:

```
heat_template_version: 2016-04-08
description: My Custom Resource
resources:
  dummy:
    type: OS::Heat::None
```

This template is associated with the name `My::Custom::Resource` in my environment file `environment.yml`:

```
resource_registry:
  My::Custom::Resource: my-custom-resource.yml
```

I use it in a test template `stack.yml`:

```
heat_template_version: 2016-04-08
description: My Stack
resources:
  test:
    type: My::Custom::Resource
```

Finally, I create the stack from the command line:

```
openstack stack create -t stack.yml -e environment.yml my-stack
```

And I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The Resource Type (My::Custom::Resource) could not be found.
```

I checked every filenames and pathes, everything looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, [the documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/heat/latest/template_guide/environment.html) says:

> The template file extension must be `.yaml` or `.template`, or it will not
>   be treated as a custom template resource.

Hence, one could say that this is the desired behavior...

I don't really understand why this limitation exists and why `.yml` extension isn't supported as well.

Furthermore, the error message could be more explicit!